# How to upload to a unix server?

Tags: linux, files, webserver, file-server

Im a part of a project group, and one of our tasks is to upload some content to a server. I am completely new to this and have some questions.

There are content on different servers(distributed on several servers). My task is to get all the content, and upload them on a single server, and make them available for others, e.g everybody that visits that server(by website) should be able to download the content.

How does one do that in a UNIX server? And how do I make them available for others?

I have no experience with servers, but I have experience with Java(also Java EE). What do I need to learn to be able to do these tasks?

Ill be getting an account for the server soon, which will give me access to it.

Please, if the question is in wrong place, or it violates any rules, let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: @Marco My Prof. told me that he were going to get me access to the server by creating an account for me during next week.(username+pass)

Comment: Quite frankly this question is a tad bit too generic. What is available across those different Unix machines? An SSH server? Go with SFTP or SSH. Do they have an FTP server? Go with FTP or FTPS. Do they have insecure `rsync` servers? Go with `rsync`. Do they have NFS or Samba? Go with `cp` ... you see? Your question really is missing a lot of info that is vital for answering it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need access to the old servers too.

Then you should be able to simply copy the contents using scp or, more efficiently, by creating a gzipped tar file of the content on the old servers, moving everything to the new one with scp and untaring there.

If this is going to be a repeated task, with changing content on the old servers, it might be better to use rsync. This will copy everything on the first run and limit itself to the changes that occured since the last rsync on later runs.

To make the content accessible via the webserver, you have to configure apache accordingly.

The details about the Unix-commands mentioned can be found in the man pages.

One example for a simple apache setup can be found here:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/apache-virtual-host/

For more details see the official apache documentation:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/

Comment: Actually, have you considered *piping* the output from `tar` (which you have to tell it to go to `-`, i.e. stdout) into `ssh user@server "tar -C $OUTDIR -xzf -"`? ;) ... no need to make those separate commands. Only reason would be if only SFTP is allowed, but no shells.

Comment: Of course, but I didn't want to put too much insides this as the OP obviously is just starting with shell programming.